# Oracle 10g - Write queries results to file

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to run 200+ select queries and append the results to a file. All queries are the same the only difference in the date-time variable. I don't have privileges to create a routine that's why I had to create all the queries. I don't have privileges to create a view or another table to store the results in. I don't have access to PL/SQL.

Now I need to create a report with the results of each one of this queries (all results are integer numbers) but I don't seem to find another solution but to run one by one and copy the results one by one.

Any of you marvelous brains can give me a hand on this? It's kind of urgent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Put your queries in a text file like so:

```
set pagesize 0;

select some_field
from some_table;

select another_field
from another_table;
/
```

2 - Save it somewhere (let's say c:\my_file.sql)

3 - Run this at the command prompt:

```
c:\>sqlplus -s username/password@database.domain.com < tmp.sql > output.txt
```

4 - Look inside "output.txt"

Comment: He'd still have to  `set echo off;` though, wouldn't he? Otherwise, wouldn't the query string be in the output?

Comment: Excellent Joseph. Will try this one too. Thank you!!

Comment: Although the query is not in the output, the column name is. Is there a way of get ride of it??

Comment: @Daniel; I modified my example with the "set pagesize 0" command, which will suppress column headers.  I also added the "-s" argument, which suppresses the sql plus intro banner.

Answer (score 2):

You can spool your output to a file.

See the [`spool`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm) (URL - Oracle 10.2 user's guide) command.

Also:

http://www.praetoriate.com/t_garmany_easysql_the_spool_command.htm

And what appears to be some layout tips:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/code/tips2004/020904.html

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work quite well. It stores the query string and also, it kind of breaks if I run 10 queries at the same time.

Comment: try `set echo off;` before running the query. That prevent the query string from being displayed.
Of course, of `echo` was on at the begining of the script, be sure to turn it back on at the end. Always leave things in the state you found them ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to sqlplus, you can run anonymous PL/SQL blocks.

```
DECLARE
 v_cnt number;
BEGIN
 select ... into v_cnt ...;
 dbms_output.put_line(v_cnt);
END;
.
spool out.log
/
spool off
```