# How to format the output file created with sqlplus?Why one of the output blocks appears two times?

Tags: xml, oracle, sqlplus

I used this steps [Oracle 10g - Write queries results to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299375/oracle-10g-write-queries-results-to-file/11357138#11357138)  in order to create a xml file. So this is the sql script which I loaded with

c:>sqlplus -s username/password@database.domain.com < tmp.sql > output.txt

```
  set pagesize 0;
    set serveroutput on
    set termout off       
    set verify off     
    set heading off    
    set long 999
    set lines 999
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET HEAD OFF

    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' || chr(10) ||
           '<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2010 rel. 2 (http://www.altova.com)-->' || chr(10) ||
           '<HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate_Flow  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate(REF-IMX-1)_v0.0.00.xsd"  xmlns:harpeml="http://www.harpeml.com"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'||chr(10)||
           '<Header>'||chr(10)||
           '<harpeml:technicalIndicator>'||'HDR'||'</harpeml:technicalIndicator>'||chr(10)||
           '<harpeml:orderNumber>'||''||lpad ( imk.nextval, 10, '0' )||'</harpeml:orderNumber>'||chr(10)||
           '<harpeml:dataSelectionDate>'||''||to_char(sysdate -  4,'DD/MM/YYYY')||''||'</harpeml:dataSelectionDate>'||chr(10)|| 
            '<harpeml:extractionTimeStamp>'||''||CURRENT_TIMESTAMP||''||'</harpeml:extractionTimeStamp>'||chr(50)||'</Header>'
            FROM dual;
    SELECT '<ExchangeRates>'||chr(10)||'<ExchangeRate>'||chr(10)||
           '<harpeml:technicalIndicator>'||'02'||'</harpeml:technicalIndicator>'||chr(10)||
           '<harpeml:currencyExchangeRateType>'||''||'D'||'</harpeml:currencyExchangeRateType>'||chr(10)
            FROM dual;
    SELECT  '<harpeml:baseCurrencyCode>'||abrev||'</harpeml:baseCurrencyCode>'  FROM(SELECT abrev FROM v_domaine where type = 'DEVISE' ORDER BY  dbms_random.normal)WHERE rownum = 1;
    SELECT 
            '<harpeml:counterCurrencyCode>'||abrev||'</harpeml:counterCurrencyCode>'FROM(SELECT  abrev FROM v_domaine where type = 'DEVISE' ORDER BY  dbms_random.normal)WHERE rownum = 1;
    SELECT 
            '<harpeml:startValidityDate>'||''||to_char(sysdate -  4,'DD/MM/YYYY')||''||'<harpeml:startValidityDate>'||chr(10)||
             '<harpeml:countryCode>'||abrev||'</harpeml:countryCode>'FROM(SELECT  abrev FROM v_domaine where type = 'pays' ORDER BY  dbms_random.normal)WHERE rownum = 1;   
    SELECT
            '<harpeml:exchangeRate>'||rpad ( imk.nextval, 3, '51' )||'</harpeml:exchangeRate>'||chr(10)||
            '<harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>'||'1'||'</harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>'||chr(10)||
            '<harpeml:dataSourceSystem>'||'freetext'||'</harpeml:dataSourceSystem>'||chr(10)||
            '</ExchangeRate>'||chr(10)||
            '</ExchangeRates>'||chr(10)||
            '</HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate_Flow>'
            from dual;
    /
```

This is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2010 rel. 2 (http://www.altova.com)-->
<HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate_Flow  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate(REF-IMX-1)_v0.0.00.xsd"  xmlns:harpeml="http://www.harpeml.com"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<harpeml:technicalIndicator>HDR</harpeml:technicalIndicator>
<harpeml:orderNumber>0000000161</harpeml:orderNumber>
<harpeml:dataSelectionDate>02/07/2012</harpeml:dataSelectionDate>
<harpeml:extractionTimeStamp>06-JUL-12 09.29.01.812631 AM +03:00</harpeml:extractionTimeStamp>2</Header>

<ExchangeRates>
<ExchangeRate>
<harpeml:technicalIndicator>02</harpeml:technicalIndicator>
<harpeml:currencyExchangeRateType>D</harpeml:currencyExchangeRateType>

<harpeml:baseCurrencyCode>BOB</harpeml:baseCurrencyCode>
<harpeml:counterCurrencyCode>SGD</harpeml:counterCurrencyCode>
<harpeml:startValidityDate>02/07/2012<harpeml:startValidityDate>
<harpeml:countryCode>BDI</harpeml:countryCode>

<harpeml:exchangeRate>162</harpeml:exchangeRate>
<harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>1</harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>
<harpeml:dataSourceSystem>freetext</harpeml:dataSourceSystem>
</ExchangeRate>
</ExchangeRates>
</HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate_Flow>

**<harpeml:exchangeRate>163</harpeml:exchangeRate>
<harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>1</harpeml:appreciationOrDepreciationReport>
<harpeml:dataSourceSystem>freetext</harpeml:dataSourceSystem>
</ExchangeRate>
</ExchangeRates>
</HarpeML_CBS_IMX_ExchangeRate_Flow>**
```

Does anyone have idea why the last block appears two times? And could you give any suggestion how to remove the empty lines from the output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL*Plus a semi-colon executes a statement.  So does a slash.

You have terminated each of your selects with a `;` which executes them.  Then you have terminated your script with a `/` which causes the last statement to be executed again.

As for the blank lines, that is just an artifact of running several distinct statements.  I wouldn't worry about them.  certainly XML doesn't care.

Hawever this is a labourious way of generating XML files: Oracle has a whole slew of XML features: [you should learn to use them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/toc.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The last block appears twice because you have a / at the end of your script - this executes the last query again.

Just replace the / with exit, and this problem should be solved.

Comment: `Exit` isn't necessarily desirable.  It's useful when invoking sqlplus in a shell script; it's a pain in the neck when we're running the scripts ourselves.

Comment: @APC That's true. But since the OP just wants to do an export from a shell script, it doesn't hurt in this case.